# Вертикально центрировать div, который находится внутри section

Tags: html, css

```
<section class="sect_1 bac" style="height: 650px">
    <div>центрировать этот див</div>
</section>
```

Comment: И в чем проблема? Что не получилось?

Comment: Ну он центрируется по размеру всего экрана а нужно чтобы центрировался по размеру родителя(section )

Comment: а где css, которым вы пытаетесь отцентрировать блок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
}      
  .box__inner {
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 8px;
  }
```

```html
 <section class="box">
   <div class="box__inner">
      Hello!
   </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

style="height: 650px" НЕ ДЕЛАЙ ТАК!

- выровнен по центру внутри относительно секции.

```css
BODY {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sect_1 {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
BORDER: 4PX SOLID GREEN;
height: 300px;
  }
  
div {
  background-color: RED;
}
```

```html
 <section class="sect_1 bac">
     <div>
      центрировать этот див
     </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Все  хорошо но вот  если нужно будет центрировать только один блок а не все. Что нужно добавить в этом случае ?

Comment: @EMOMALIEV, родителю display: flex, ребёнку-блоку - align-self: center; align-items убрать

Comment: @EMOMALIEV я не знаю сколько у вас блоков, "а если..." не совсем хороший вопрос. 
Погугли центрирование и позиуионирование css.